# VB6 Shape control BorderWidth >1 with Dash style?

Tags: vb6, controls, shapes

When you set a Shape's BorderWidth > 1 in VB6, the Style is forced to be a plain line.

I'd like a DASHED (or Dotted) border with a thicker (say borderwidth=3) size.

any way to do that without drawing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, under the hood a [GDI Pen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183509(v=vs.85).aspx) is used to draw the shape and the 1 twip limit is imposed there.

> `PS_DASH`
>
> The pen is dashed. This style is valid only when the pen width
>   is one or less in device units.

This of course also means you cannot use the GDI API to do it directly for you either.

Perhaps draw a series of lines offset by 1 twip.